# Porque el error Cannot read property '0' of undefined en un arreglo bidimensional

Tags: javascript, array

Hola a todos tengo el `Error` mencionado cuando quiero almacenar datos, guardo en un arreglo coordenadas y luego cuando quiero almacenarlas me arroja dicho `Error`.

```
//Declaracion de variables
var coordinates = [];
var valid = 1;

function addMarker(location) 
{
  if (valid < 6) 
  {
    valid++;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
      position: location,
      map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    var coordinate = [location.lat(), location.lng()];
    coordinates.push(coordinate);
    console.log(location.lat() + ', ' + location.lng())
    console.log(coordinates);
    console.log(markers);
    alert(location);
  }
  else
  {
    alert('No puedes agregar mas puntos de encuentro');
  }

}//addMarker

function registerSpots()
{
  console.log('POSTING spots...');
  for (var i = 1; i <= valid; i++) 
  {
    //create request
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //prepare request
    console.log(sessionStorage.userId);
    x.open('POST', '', true);
    //form data
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('student', sessionStorage.userId);
    fd.append('slot', i);
    fd.append('latitude', coordinates[i][0]);
    fd.append('longitude', coordinates[i][1]);
    console.log(fd);
    x.send(fd);
    console.log(fd);
    x.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
      if (x.status == 200 && x.readyState == 4) 
      {

        var JSONdata = JSON.parse(x.responseText); console.log(JSONdata);
        alert(JSONdata.errorMessage);
        //show buildings
        console.log(x.responseText);
      }//if
    }//x.onreadystatechange
  }//For
}//RegisterSpots
```

El error lo marca aquí

```
fd.append('latitude', coordinates[i][0]);
```

De antemano gracias por leer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu variable `valid` va de 1 a 5. 
Tu arreglo `coordinates` va, por lo tanto, de 0 a 4 (los arrays empiezan desde cero en js... y en casi todos los lenguajes salvo SQL y sus parientes).

Cuando haces:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= valid; i++) {
   ... operación con coordinates[i]...
}
```

Primero, estás omitiendo el elemento 0 del array, y segundo estás pidiendo `coordinates[5]` que es undefined y por tanto no tiene un elemento [0].

Debieras hacer:

```
for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
   ... operación con coordinates[i]...
}
```

o mejor todavía

```
var coords_length = coordinates.length;
for (var i = 0; i < coords_length; i++) {
   ... operación con coordinates[i]...
}
```

comentario al margen: no veo donde estás definiendo `markers`.